# jekyll theme rendering doesn't apply

Tags: jekyll

when I excuting `jekyll serve` css working well,
but after `git push` and enter sh95119.github.io doesn't apply css. Please help me. I have spent 3h solve this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/sh95119/sh95119.github.io.git <- this is site

Comment: 3h?! you should be exhausted

Comment: Please look at the help topic for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Once you've looked at these please reword your question as it currently does not have enough information to allow us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In _config.yml, change :

```
baseurl: "/jekyll-theme-prologue"
```

to

```
baseurl: ""
```